# How to properly use .SWC packages in Flash CS 4

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, swc

I've googled a lot trying to find how to properly import and use .swc files in Flash CS 4, tried lots of different methods but none seem to work.

What I've done is:
1. Placed it in my "D:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\en\Configuration\Components" folder. It does however not show up in the component inspector.
2. Added it in Publishing Settings as a Library and External Library, still can't seem to use it.

I've also tried adding "import org.osflash.signals;" after each method but I receive the error "1172: Definition org.osflash:signals could not be found."

So what I'm asking for is an easy way to get the .swc package working code-wise with all classes imported etc. The .swc file is as you may have guessed [as3signals](http://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(shortcut are for PC)*

- Put your library file wherever you want
- Now you have two choices:

  1. You want to be able to use it for all the project you made

     - go into preferences panel (ctrl+U)
     - click on the button action script3 parameters, and add the path where is your swc (click on the second '+' button )
  2. You want it only for your current project

     - go into publication parameters (ctrl+shift+F12)
     - click on the flash tab
     - click on the parameters button in front of actionscript 3.0
     - click on the library path tab, and add your swc path.

Comment: This is what I've done, and added the "import org.osflash.signals;" but it says it can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the intent of SWC file, you can just drag it into your Library, alongside all your other MovieClips etc.

It seems to me that this is the way AS3Signals wants to be used - it's not a Flash "Component", per se. Adding it to the Components directory will only make it available in the Components panel, where you can easily drag it into your Library, or maybe onto the Stage (which has the same effect).

Any progress or detail available?

Comment: Just tried that with my old document and a new one, both saying "One or more files were not imported because there were problems reading them."
I used a newly downloaded as3-signals-v0.7.swc.

Comment: That doesn't sound good. What URL did you download it from? I can check to see if I get the same error. Also, what version of Flash are you using?

Comment: http://github.com/robertpenner/as3-signals/downloads
Flash CS4 Professional right now.