# Facebook API & Adobe Air/Flash Support

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, api, flash, air

I'm currently struggling with a problem that has arose with using the Facebook Graph API and integrating it with Adobe Air.

I've tried everything. I've tried linkage with amfphp and I've tried classes. I've downloaded the Adobe/Facebook swc but I'm just wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction if I wanted to use the Flash CS6 timeline to link with the API (As most tutorials are using classes or .as files) and just using it in general in Flash CS6. It is an Air For iOS app so I want to use the Mobile api and I just want to be able to create it within the Flash timeline. Your support is greatly appreciated & any links that point to the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want this you want that meaning you have no code and no clue and you want somebody to do the job for you.

Comment: I'm looking for a tutorial or a framework to work off of...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should know a bit how flash works (if you don't) and will be so easy to understand the differences between the code in timeline and the code structured in classes or .as files as you said. I left you a little resource i hope it helps.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j3rlEMnBEHQ

With the flash API, you have to import the .swc library (in your case the GraphAPI_Mobile_1_8_1.swc) in your .fla document and after that you will be able to access to the functions of the library from your code doing the respective calls FB.login() etc etc.

Here there is a SO answer that explains you how to import the library:
[How to properly use .SWC packages in Flash CS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891979/how-to-properly-use-swc-packages-in-flash-cs-4)

I hope it helps you to solve your problems.
Greetings.